# How can I supress Delphi DataSnap error message dialogs?

Tags: delphi, messagebox, dcom, datasnap

We run a DataSnap Delphi 2009 application on Windows 2003 Server. DataSnap Client and Server are on the same computer, using DCOM over Borland Socketserver. The client runs a background batch job.

Sometimes, we discover that the client can not connect to the server application and displays a message dialog on the server desktop indicating for example "Could not connect to server. Network path could not be found." or "Objectexporter not found."

Our Delphi client code never uses a message dialog to show errors or exceptions, instead we use try ... except .. finally ... end and logging to handle connect errors, so I guess the dialog is created by a DataSnap method. Is there a way to suppress this modal dialog box?

Update: all exceptions are handled in lower level routines, the main loop takes care of disconnecting and reconnecting when an exception is raised (handled or unhandled):

```
  while True do
  begin
    Connect;
    while True do
    begin
      try
        DoMyWork;
      except
        Break;
      end;
    end;
    Disconnect;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3):

solution 1)
maybe an global hook over the application.onexception can handle the problem

http://www.chami.com/tips/delphi/011497D.html

solution 2)

use EurekaLog or MadExcept in order to find out from where the application raise that error, and handle the error.

solution 3)

a global hook over the application message dialogs, a hook example is bellow

http://delphi.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=delphi&cdn=compute&tm=43&f=22&su=p284.9.336.ip_p504.1.336.ip_&tt=2&bt=1&bts=1&zu=http%3A//www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/apps7.htm

you query all the application's messages, and when you catch that window then you process the message not the application. because i don't have now the time I don't know exactly which is the wmessage raised by messagedlg.

hope that helped.

best regards,

Comment: The application uses madExcept and exception logging, it looks like no exception is thrown when the error message box appears